# How to refactor duplicate Firestore document IDs in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, duplicates

I'm doing my very first IOS app using Cloud Firestore and have to make the same queries to my database repeatedly. I would like to get rid of the duplicate lines of code. This is examples of func where documents ID are duplicated. Also I using other queries as `.delete()`, `.addSnapshotListener()`, `.setData()`. Should I refactor all that queries somehow or leave them because they were used just for one time?

```
    @objc func updateUI() {

        inputTranslate.text = ""
        inputTranslate.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        let user =  Auth.auth().currentUser?.email
        let docRef = db.collection(K.FStore.collectionName).document(user!)
        docRef.getDocument { [self] (document, error) in

        if let document = document, document.exists {

            let document = document
            let label = document.data()?.keys.randomElement()!
            self.someNewWord.text = label
            
                // Fit the label into screen
            self.someNewWord.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            
            self.checkButton.isHidden = false
            self.inputTranslate.isHidden = false
            self.deleteBtn.isHidden = false

        } else {

            self.checkButton.isHidden = true
            self.inputTranslate.isHidden = true
            self.deleteBtn.isHidden = true
            self.someNewWord.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            self.someNewWord.text = "Add your first word to translate"

            updateUI()

            }
     }
}
          
@IBAction func checkButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    let user =  Auth.auth().currentUser?.email
    let docRef = db.collection(K.FStore.collectionName).document(user!)
    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        let document = document
        
        let label = self.someNewWord.text!
        let currentTranslate = document!.get(label) as? String

        let translateField = self.inputTranslate.text!.lowercased().trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)

        if translateField == currentTranslate {
            self.inputTranslate.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) { [self] in
                self.inputTranslate.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                updateUI()}

        } else {
            self.inputTranslate.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            self.inputTranslate.shakingAndRedBg()
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) { [self] in
                self.inputTranslate.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                self.inputTranslate.text = ""
            }
        }
    }
}

func deletCurrentWord () {

    let user =  Auth.auth().currentUser?.email
    let docRef = db.collection(K.FStore.collectionName).document(user!)
    docRef.getDocument { (document, err) in
        let document = document
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            
        } else {
              
            let  array = document!.data()
            let counter = array!.count
                
        if counter == 1 {
                    
                    // The whole document will deleted together with a last word in list.
            let user =  Auth.auth().currentUser?.email
            self.db.collection(K.FStore.collectionName).document(user!).delete() { err in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error removing document: \(err)")
                } else {
                    self.updateUI()
                }
            }
                        
        } else {
            // A current word will be deleted

            let user =  Auth.auth().currentUser?.email
            let wordForDelete  = self.someNewWord.text!
                    
            self.db.collection(K.FStore.collectionName).document(user!).updateData([
                wordForDelete: FieldValue.delete()
                    ]) { err in
                            
                    if let err = err {
                        print("Error updating document: \(err)")
                    } else {
                        self.updateUI()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Another query example

```
       func loadMessages() {
            let user =  Auth.auth().currentUser?.email
            let docRef = db.collection(K.FStore.collectionName).document(user!)
            docRef.addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            
            self.messages = []
            
            if let e = error {
                print(e)
            } else {
                if let snapshotDocuments = querySnapshot?.data(){
                    
                    for item in snapshotDocuments {
                        
                        if let key = item.key as? String, let translate = item.value as? String {
                                                   
                            let newMessage = Message(key: key, value: translate)
                            self.messages.append(newMessage)
                        }
                    }
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.messages.sort(by: {$0.value > $1.value})
                            self.secondTableView.reloadData()
                            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.messages.count - 1, section: 0)
                            self.secondTableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: false)
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
enum Error {
    case invalidUser
    case noDocumentFound
}

func fetchDocument(onError: @escaping (Error) -> (), completion: @escaping (FIRQueryDocument) -> ())  {
    guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email else {
        onError(.invalidUser)
        return
    }
    db.collection(K.FStore.collectionName).document(user).getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let error = error {
            onError(.noDocumentFound)
        } else {
            completion(document)
        }
    }
}

func updateUI() {
    fetchDocument { [weak self] error in
        self?.hideShowViews(shouldHide: true, newWordText: nil)
    } completion: { [weak self] document in
        guard document.exists else {
            self?.hideShowViews(shouldHide: true, newWordText: nil)
            return
        }
        self?.hideShowViews(shouldHide: false, newWordText: document.data()?.keys.randomElement())
    }
}


private func hideShowViews(shouldHide: Bool, newWordText: String?) {
    checkButton.isHidden = shouldHide
    inputTranslate.isHidden = shouldHide
    deleteBtn.isHidden = shouldHide
    someNewWord.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    someNewWord.text = newWordText ?? "Add your first word to translate"
}
```

The `updateUI` method can easily be refactored using a simple guard statement and then taking out the common code into a separate function. I also used `[weak self]` so that no memory leaks or retain cycles occur.

Now, you can follow the similar approach for rest of the methods.

1. Use `guard let` instead of `if let` to avoid nesting.
2. Use `[weak self]` for async calls to avoid memory leaks.
3. Take out the common code into a separate method and use a `Bool` flag to hide/show views.

**Update for step 3:**
You can create methods similar to async APIs for `getDocument()` or `delete()` etc and on completion you can update UI or perform any action. You can also create a separate class and move the `fetchDocument()` and other similar methods in there and use them.

Comment: Step1 and 2 were useful! I am grateful to you!
Could you explain more about  step3 how to put the common code into a separate method? 
The reference to database is  a if-else statement and I have no idea how to split it to different methods. Thank you

Comment: Are you referring to `func deletCurrentWord()`?

Comment: I mean every methods where this rows used, including func deletCurrentWord(). It's common lines of code 

        let user =  Auth.auth().currentUser?.email
        let docRef = db.collection(K.FStore.collectionName).document(user!)
        docRef.getDocument { [weak self] (document, error) in
                guard let document = document

I can't move this reference into another method because it's a part of if-else statement. Do you know some way  to do this?

Comment: wow this is really what I was looking for! This way of refactoring  is very interesting, it's new to me. It seems that this way is really suitable, I only need to fix one mistake "Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer" at  this row

    guard let document, document.exists else {

Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: That's because the document is not optional so you can use `guard document.exists else {` instead. Also, please upvote and mark the answer as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: It's works! Thanks a lot for help, i'm deeply appreciate!

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately the error "Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer"  appeared again. Also I have a new error "Expected expression in conditional" after using guard document.exists else { instead. Could you explain how to fix that?

Comment: @Helga the `guard` statement can be used with `Optional` and `Bool` values. Double check the type that the `completion` handler returns in the `fetchDocument` method. If it's a non-optional value you just need to check whether the document exists or not. You can do that using a simple `if-else` statement or a `guard` statement.

Comment: This time all works as well) I used if-else statement and refactored all needed methods. Thank you!